# Converting iframe code to jquery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am using an Iframe to load the contents within an iframe every 5 seconds. It works fine. What happens is, it just keeps blinking every time it loads, which is bit annoying.

I want to convert the iframe code to scrolling div so the iframe src contents keep getting loaded every 5 seconds and the blinking should go away.

Here is my code:

My Home Page (*INDEX.HTML*) has:

```
<iframe src="messages.php#bottom" width="674" height="476" frameborder="0" name="main" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="auto"/></iframe>
```

The Contents of Messages.php is like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() { setTimeout("window.location.href='messages.php';", 5000) }; // 5000 = 2 seconds (it's in milliseconds)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php Application.logs ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use this file:

https://gist.github.com/aklump/5470863 - but not able to spin my head around how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a meta refresh Tag in messages.php

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

OR you could use Javascript with setInterval to refresh the src of the Source...

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 5000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["frameNameHere"].location.reload();
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Try adding this into `index.html`:

```
<script>
    // Prevent variables from being global      
    (function () {

      /*
          1. Inject CSS which makes iframe invisible
      */

    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || 
              document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);


    /*
        2. When window loads, remove that CSS, 
           making iframe visible again
    */

    window.onload = function() {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }

})();
</script>
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay, remove all the previous code that you copied from here and try this instead:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,5000);
    $.get('messages.php#bottom', function(data) {
        $('#content_div_id').html(data);    
    });
}
</script>
```

And then replace your iFrame with this:

```
<div id="content_div_id">
<iframe src="messages.php#bottom" width="674" height="476" frameborder="0" name="main" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: where i need to define it, inside messages.php or outside in index.html file the <script> code

Comment: btw, the question is: even iff i make this script works, will the blinking go away, i think not, my concern was blinking should go away

Comment: @Initiater The `meta` tag has to go in the `head` section of `messages.php` and the `script` can basically go wherever you want in `index.html`. Try out the code and let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: okay, i tried and it has same behavior as iframe, blinking every 5 seconds, it do work, but blinking  is still there

Comment: You tried both the `meta` tag in the `head` section of `messages.php` and the `script` in `index.html`?

Comment: ok, removing the code u gave e very start, i should only add the edited one correct

Comment: My Console Error: `http://prntscr.com/f0tfj8` and the view-source of the index.html page `http://prntscr.com/f0tfrm`

Comment: Hmm... When you put in the original `script` code did you add `name="postmessage"` to your iframe tag as well?

Comment: yes, i did, i even named the iframe as id to postmessage too

Comment: did you saw my screenshot, i pasted it, it did not worked with new one too

Comment: but it keeps blinking again and again

Comment: @Initiater Try Edit 2.

Comment: Now it is replacing the bottom part which has a form to post the contents with this `http://prntscr.com/f0ufmz` That is the default message when the window is loaded first time

Comment: Soo... Does it still blink? Also that message looks like it's from the console.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the iframe, use a [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) element. For example:

```
<div id="messageContainer"></div>
```

Then use jQuery's [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to trigger an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) request, though it could be argued that jQuery isn't needed (*vanilla* Javscript could be used with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) - Read [this site](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/) for more information about eliminating jQuery).

When the request to *messages.php* is finished, update the innerHTML of the container with the response (i.e. with [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)). Since jquery AJAX requests (e.g. called via $.get(), $.post(), etc.) return a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object, which implements the Promise interface (see [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information). So [.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) can be used to trigger a callback when the AJAX request is finished.

```
 $.get('messages.php')
    .done(function(response) {
            messageContainer = $('#messageContainer');
            messageContainer.html(response);
    });
```

Put that AJAX call in a function and use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call a function every 5 seconds.

```
setInterval(requestMessage, 5000);
```

Additionally, the code below scrolls the container to the bottom using jQuery's [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method.

```js
//ensure DOM has loaded before interacting with it
$(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(requestMessage, 5000); 
   console.log('interval set - every 5 seconds');    
});
function requestMessage() {
    $.get('http://samonela.scienceontheweb.net/PHP/messages2.php')
        .done(function(response) {
                messageContainer = $('#messageContainer');
                messageContainer.html(response);
                //scroll container to the bottom
                messageContainer.scrollTop(messageContainer[0].scrollHeight);
                
                
        });
}
```

```css
#messageContainer {
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageContainer">
</div>
```